# How to hide arrow on the left of the DataGrid headers?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Check the link below
http://tpstatic.com/img/usermedia/lN3his36gUeN0P0-1csn0A/original.png

What I'm trying to do is to get rid of the arrow in the left corner. The thing is I'm making my DataGrid from code, not in XAML. Here is the code:

```
DataGrid reportDataGrid = new DataGrid();
reportDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
reportDataGrid.CanUserAddRows = false;
reportDataGrid.IsReadOnly = true;
reportDataGrid.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
reportDataGrid.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
reportDataGrid.RowHeaderWidth = 0;
reportDataGrid.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column;
```

And some Column definition and binding:

```
var caseNameCol= new DataGridTextColumn();
caseNameCol.Header = "Case Name";
Binding binding = new Binding("CaseName");
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
binding.Source = list;
caseNameCol.Binding = binding;
reportDataGrid.Columns.Add(caseNameCol);

var caseItemNameCol= new DataGridTextColumn();
caseItemNameCol.Header = "Case Item Name";
Binding caseBinding = new Binding("CaseItemName");
caseBinding .Source = list;
caseBinding .Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
caseItemNameCol.Binding = caseBinding ;
reportDataGrid.Columns.Add(caseItemNameCol);
```

Everything works fine but the problem is that the arrow remains in my datagrid. Any idea how to remove it from datagrid?

Answer (score 2):

Prepare to get down and dirty for this one.

Firstly, we are going to define a ControlTemplate for the datagrid.  This will be based off the default, with one minor change.  You can find the default template on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="dgControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Border x:Name="border"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
            </Border.Background>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer"
                    Focusable="false"
                    Background="Black">
                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Button Focusable="false"
                      Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"

                       Loaded="theScaryButton_Loaded"  

                      Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey 
                  ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, 
                  TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}"

                      Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, 
                  ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, 
                  Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                      Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>

                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                              Grid.Column="1"
                                              Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, 
                  ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, 
                  Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />

                            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />

                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                         Grid.Column="2"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Orientation="Vertical"
                         ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                         Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                         Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                         Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Orientation="Horizontal"
                           ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                           Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                           Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                           Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

The line we added to this is:

```
Loaded="theScaryButton_Loaded"
```

Meanwhile in the code behind of our window...

```
//set up datagrid...
this.reportDataGrid.Template = this.Resources["dgControlTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
```

and also

```
private void theScaryButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //this is a baddy way to do this.  better to recurse through visual tree
    //or try your luck at FindName/GetTemplateChild nonsense

    VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sender as FrameworkElement, 0), 1).SetValue(FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed);
}
```

There is a Nasty Little Polygon buried inside The Scary Button.  For the sake of example, I added some baddy code to grab him and shut him up.  The better way to do this is to recurse the visual tree, or perhaps derive from Button and try your luck with GetTemplateChild.  This should be enough to get you started, though.  Forgive me if this is vastly overcomplicated, I come from Silverlight World, where everything is vastly overcomplicated.

You may also consider trying to just work your way through the visual tree to find the Nasty Little Polygon, but be prepared to dig through not one, not two, but three control templates on your way down.

Comment: Thank you for the detail answer. I'll give it a try and let you know if I manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RowHeaderWidth property:

```
<my:DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" />
```

Note that you can also specify a style or template for it also, should you decide you really do like it and want to keep it because you can do something cool with it.

Comment: Check my code. I did use that property but no effect.

Comment: Ok try this reportDataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = false;

Comment: I don't have RowHeadersVisible property.